# How to do a Cartesian product in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

Is there a way to perform a Cartesian product in DolphinDB？

For example, for a=[1,2] and b=[3,4] I would like to have [1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
a = 1 2
b = 3 4
cross(def(x,y):[x,y], a,b).flatten()
```